Did my friend commit adultery and will he need to be stoned to death?
My friend just recently got married. He has been a porn addict for a very long time and thought marriage would fix his addiction issue. However, after the marriage, there was some family issues and his newly wed wife gave less attention to him for some time. This led him to feel depressed and lonely and so he turned to porn again. However, this time around, he has crossed the line a little. He turned to online cam girls and had cybersex with them. He now feels very ashamed and disgusted of his actions and is very worried what consequences he might face due to this. He has not told his wife or anyone except me about this. He is remorseful and is seeking forgiveness from Allah. However, he has some questions:

Is this considered fornication because no actual sexual intercourse outside marriage happened.
Will he be punished and will it be same as fornication - stoning to death?
Will he be forgiven by Allah? What should he do to be granted forgiveness by Allah?

Thank you.

Also see Will Allah forgive me for doing X ?

assalam alaikom No, cybersex is not considered fornication (zina) in the classical sense, which involves actual physical intercourse outside of marriage. However, it is still a major sin because it involves sexual immorality, which is prohibited in Islam. The Prophet Muhammad (peace be upon him) said:
"The eyes commit adultery, and their adultery is looking (at unlawful things); the hands commit adultery, and their adultery is touching (unlawfully); the feet commit adultery, and their adultery is walking toward the unlawful; the mouth commits adultery, and its adultery is kissing (unlawfully)..." (Sahih Muslim)
No, he will not be punished with stoning (which is the punishment for zina—fornication or adultery) unless it involves actual physical adultery with someone outside the marriage. The punishment for other sexual sins, including watching pornography or engaging in cybersex, is left to Allah’s discretion, but it is a serious sin, and the focus should be on repentance
Yes, Allah is always ready to forgive those who turn to Him in sincere repentance. The Qur'an says:
"Say, 'O My servants who have harmed yourselves, do not despair of Allah's mercy. Allah forgives all sins; He is truly the Most Forgiving, the Most Merciful.'" (Quran 39:53)
Encourage him to make sincere Tawbah (repentance), seek Allah’s forgiveness, and strive to avoid repeating the mistake. Allah’s mercy is vast, and He forgives those who turn to Him with a pure heart.
ALLAH KNOW BEST
